# making a trigger from html to ifttt

Tags: javascript, html, triggers, ifttt

**Background:**

I am working on a temperature monitoring project Obniz microcontroller. The goal is to make a notification whenever the temperature exceed the selected threshold.

I searched a lot about making a trigger so that ifttt can read my trigger but I can't find the perfect way for my temperature monitoring project.

**This is my js code that I want to be triggered:**

```
var t = document.getElementById("tThresh");
var tempThresh = t.options[t.selectedIndex].value;
if (obj.temperature > tempThresh){
    led1.on()
    obniz.display.print("The temperature is too high")              
    obniz.display.clear();
};
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Why not a litle setTimeout looking each 1 - 5 minutes the latest temperature and determinate in this one if latest temperature is higher than the limit if yes do what you need to do.

Example:

```
var limit = 60;
var current = 30;
setTimeout(function(){
   if(current >= limit){
      window.alert("Temperature is being a litle bit high.");
   }
}, 3000);
```